# Filter by date Podio JSON

Tags: json, podio

I'm trying to filter by "created_on" date in the Podio API, but somehow it always returns all the items. This is thre request I"m sending:

```
"filters": 
{"created_on": 
  {
    "from": 2017-12-11,
    "to": 2017-12-13
  }
}
```

I'm calling the following URL with a POST request. "http://app.podio.com/item/app/{id}/filter"
Hopefully anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a string & not an int in the filter.

```
filters: 
  {"created_on": 
    {
      "from": "2017-12-11",
      "to": "2017-12-13"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove "" from filters.

```
filters: 
{"created_on": 
  {
    "from": 2017-12-11,
    "to": 2017-12-13
  }
}
```

here is the list of fileter documantation
https://developers.podio.com/doc/filters